# code first migrations for document dbs (cosmos)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

how do you manage document db (e.g. cosmos) operations during a deployment with a code-first strategy?
It could be any CRUD operation, the type of operation isn't really the concern, more about how to execute it as part of a deployment. The equivalent of Entity Framework Migrations Up Down pattern, but without EF

thanks

Comment: Entity Framework migrations update the database schema. CosmosDb has no notion of schema and doesn't enforce any model structure besides the id and partition key, so what are you actually proposing to do in this migration, conceptually?

Comment: hi Tom - the main use case i was thinking was a bulk data update i.e. adding a new element to documents of a certain type (to match new functionality of the deployment), some sort of data manipulation etc. Basically, something to be performed in conjunction with the software deployment was the main requirement. thanks